# Serial Data, threading, and check boxes

Tags: c#, multithreading, checkbox

I am working on a project for a physics class and would like to try and get an app together to perform the following.  The test unit has a serial port on it that is outputting data at 1 Hz.  I would like to have an app that will read the serial port data and save it to a file.  I have created this in a Console app and it works fine.  Now, I would like a GUI.  On the main screen of the GUI I would like a couple of check boxes.  One where the user can add a timestamp to the incoming data stream, one to output the data to a text file, and may be one to send the data to my graphite graphing server.

So, I am looking for some pointers here.  Right now, I have a connect button.  When pressed, it opens the serial port and performs a serial.readline()  But if no data is currently being pushed across the link, the app is locked up.  So I am assuming I need to use threading.  Does this sound correct?

And last, how do I handle the check boxes?  I would like 4 total buttons.  Connect/Disconnect Record/Pause. At least these is my thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a thread for the serial port just hook into the [DataReceived](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived.aspx) event.

As for the checkboxes hook into the [CheckedChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checkedchanged.aspx) event.

So it would look something like:

```
private bool paused;
private SerialPort sp;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    sp = new SerialPort();
    sp.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(sp_DataReceived);
}

private void sp_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!paused)
    {
        string indata = sp.ReadExisting();

        //Display the data
        //To avoid cross thread problems do something like this
        Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            textBox1.Text += indata;
        }));

        //Or if you are just writing to the console 
        Console.WriteLine(indata); //Thread safe

        //Timestamp checkbox
        if (checkBox3.Checked)
        {
            //Display timestamp using DateTime.Now  
        }

    //Write to file checkbox
    if (checkBox4.Checked)
    {
        using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(path, true))
        {
            file.WriteLine(indata);
        } 
    }
}
}

//Pause/Resume Checkbox
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    paused = checkBox1.Checked;
}

//Connect/Disconnect checkbox
private void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox2.Checked)
    {
        sp.Open();
    }
    else
    {
        sp.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect `DataReceived` will actually be raised on a background thread and so you would need to marshal the commands to update the UI controls onto the UI thread.

Comment: Do not use Invoke in a DataReceived event handler, it is very likely to cause deadlock when the UI thread closes the port.  Only use BeginInvoke.  The high rate this code invokes furthermore makes it likely the UI thread will freeze.